# window.name code errors - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The idea of the code is: set `window.name` to **1** if the `function showHint` part of the code was executed, otherwise - set window name to **0** (default).
JSFiddle [reports](https://jsfiddle.net/05b6mLsx/) several errors in my code. I'm new to JavaScript - what exactly am i doing wrong?

```
function start()
{
   if (window.name == "1")
   {
        window.name = "0";
   }
   else
   {

   function showHint(id1, id2) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id1);
   var y = document.getElementById(id2);
   var blurOffClass = "blur_filter_off";

   if (!x.classList.contains(blurOffClass)) {
     x.classList.add(blurOffClass);
  }

   if (!y.classList.contains(blurOffClass)) {
     y.classList.add(blurOffClass);
  }
   }                             
}
```

Comment: You have an unmatched `{` (i.e. there is no matching `}`) and you are declaring a function inside another function and never call it, which doesn't seem logical to me. Maybe the line `function showHint(id1, id2) {` is superfluous? That removes both warnings. By the way you'd spot these issues like "unmatched `{`" much easier if you'd indent your code properly, don't underestimate the value of the visual cues it can give!

Comment: Well, the code was written by someone else (can't ask that person for some reason and i don't know JS at all) and they told me: "use `window.name` to track if `function showHint(id1, id2)` code was executed (after CSS-button click) or not. If yes - set `window.name` to 1, otherwise - to 0." So i decided he supposed to _combine_ these 2 codes into 1 single piece. You mean i misunderstood him and these are 2 _independent_ (functionally) codes, right? Thank you for commenting this!